# /n não funciona em email com spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

private String textoChamado(FormularioOuvidoriaDTO formularioOuvidoriaDTO) {

```
    String aux;

    aux = "Cartão Unimed: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getNumeroCartaoUnimed() + "\n\n" +
    "***    Número do Protocolo: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getNumeroProtocolo() + "\n\n" +
    "***    Nome Completo: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getNomeCompleto() +  "\n\n" +
    "***    Nome Social: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getNomeSocial() + "\n\n" +
    "***    Cpf/Cnpj: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getCpfCnpj() + "\n\n" +
    "***    Profissão: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getProfissao() + "\n\n" +
    "***    Cidade: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getCidade() + "\n\n" +
    "***    Telefone para contato: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getTelefone() + "\n\n" +
    "***    Email: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getEmail() + "\n\n" +
    "***    Número do Protocolo Ovudoria: " + formularioOuvidoriaDTO.getProtocoloFormulario() + "\n\n" +
    "***     Ouvidoria - Formulário Portal";

    log.debug("Conteúdo aux: " + aux );
    return aux;

}
```

/// Essa mensagem vai ser enviada para o email, e o /n não funciona com ela, ou seja na mensagem todos os campos estão juntos, existe algo que possa fazer usando java ou então podem me dar uma luz sobre como transferir essa mensagem para html

Answer (score -1):

Você está inserindo isso no corpo HTML do e-mail, certo? Tentou usar **`<br>`** no lugar do **`/n`**?